# Determine number of preceding equal elements

Tags: numpy

Using numpy, given a sorted 1D array, how to efficiently obtain a 1D array with equal size where the value at each position is the number of preceding equal elements? I have very large arrays and processing each element in Python code one way or another is not acceptable.

Example:

```
input  = [0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6]
output = [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6])
uni,counts=np.unique(A, return_counts=True)
out=np.concatenate([np.arange(n) for n in counts])
print(out)
```

Not certain about the efficiency (probably better way to form the `out` array rather than concatenating), but a very straightforward way to get the result you are looking for. Counts the unique elements, then does `np.arange` on each count to get the ascending sequence, then concatenates these arrays together.